# Mathematica, NMinimize: Equality constraint involving function is "invalid"

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

In Mathematica, I've defined the following, in order to try and solve an optimization problem:

```
costVector := {710000, 610000, 650000, 910000, 720000, 570000} 

cost[x_] := Total[IntegerDigits[x, 2, 6]*costVector]

coverage[x_] := coveragex @@ IntegerDigits[x, 2, 6]

coveragex[a_ , b_, c_, d_, e_, f_ ] := 
 Complement[
  Union[a*{4, 5, 6}, b*{1, 5}, c*{5, 6, 7}, d*{1, 3, 4, 7}, 
   e*{2, 3, 5}, f*{2, 6}], {0}]

goal = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

To sum up the problem: I'd like to find a six-digit binary value x such that cost[x] is as small as possible, while fulfilling the criteria that calling coverage[x] gives the specified list of integers goal. To find this value, I attempt to use NMinimize in the following manner:

```
NMinimize[{cost[x], {(coverage[x]) == goal,
        x <= 63, x >= 0}}, x]|
```

My problem is that I then receive the following error:

```
NMinimize::bcons: "The following constraints are not valid: {coveragex[x,2,6]==goal,x>=0,x<=63}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables"
```

For some reason, Mathematica seems to feel that the constraint comparing coverage[x] with goal is not an equality. I've been tearing my hair out trying to find out why. Have I just made some kind of syntax error, or am I using NMinimize in an incorrect manner? Is this doable in any way?

Answer (score 2):

2<sup>6</sup> possibilities is not *that* much, so I'd use a simple iteration over all possibilities:

```
MinimalBy[Select[Range[2^6 - 1], coverage[#] == goal &], cost]
```

I don't know enough Mathematica to understand the error message, but `coverage[x,2,6]` looks like the wrong number of arguments here. I also fear that `NMinimize` has no way to know that it should only try integers, and that other things will break if non-integers are supplied. But that's just guessing.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose you're right about that. I'll give your suggestion a try, thanks!